# How to perform 0 to 1 Normalization in excel

Tags: excel, normalization

I have an excel file with a column containing some numbers i need to normalize the distribution between 0 and 1 using this formula x-min(distribution)/max(distribution)-min(distribution). any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thats a pretty simple formula - have you tried it? All you need is Max(), Min() and some basic arithmetic.

Comment: I have tried this =(G9-MIN(G9:G12))/(MAX(G9:G12)-MIN(G9:G12)) but when i autofill cells get iterated and min and max values are getting changed

Comment: Use `Min($G$9:$G$12)` etc.  Adding the $ to the row/column fixes the reference so it won't increment when you fill it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this:

```
=(G9-MIN($G$9:$G:$12))/(MAX($G$9:$G$12)-MIN($G$9:$G$12))
```

Comment: thanks its working
=(G9-MIN($G$9:$G$12))/(MAX($G$9:$G$12)-MIN($G$9:$G$12))